# Error 500: could not initialize a collection in hibernate mapping

Tags: oracle, set, hibernate-mapping, ora-01722

I am a newbie for Hibernate. Hope you guys can help me debug below error which really make me crazy.

I got a table called CONTENT_WORKGROUP which will map to another table called CONTENT_WORKGROUP_ROLE. Below is the table structure and sample data:

### CONTENT_WORKGROUP

1. CM_WORKGROUP_ID         NUMBER(15,0)
2. WORKGROUP_ID                  NUMBER(15,0)
3. ROLE_ID                  VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)

### CONTENT_WORKGROUP_ROLE

1. CM_WORKGROUP_ROLE_ID NUMBER(15,0)
2. ROLE_ID                   VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
3. FUNCTION_ID          VARCHAR2(40 BYTE)

**P/S: One user workgroup can have multiple role (Creator, Admin, Approver). The function(Add, Edit, Delete) that can perform by this workgroup can be query from CONTENT_WORKGROUP_ROLE.**

Sample DATA:

### CONTENT_WORKGROUP

CM_WORKGROUP_ID            WORKGROUP_ID            ROLE_ID
1                        136                        Creator
2                        137                        Administrator
3                        136                        Administrator

### CONTENT_WORKGROUP_ROLE

CM_WORKGROUP_ROLE_ID        ROLE_ID        FUNCTION_ID

1            Creator                        Copy
2            Creator                        Edit
3            Creator                        Delete
4            Creator                        Add
5            Administrator               Edit
6            Administrator               Approve
7            Administrator               Reject

However, I am getting the error when I get the SET of ContentWorkgroupRole hold by particular workgroup.

[11/23/10 15:28:56:053 SGT] 00000039 SystemOut     O [23/11/2010 15:28:56.053] ERROR JDBCExceptionReporter - ORA-01722: invalid number

[11/23/10 15:28:56:100 SGT] 00000039 ServletWrappe E   SRVE0068E: Uncaught exception thrown in one of the service methods of the servlet: action. Exception thrown : javax.servlet.ServletException: could not initialize a collection: [corp.celcom.next.infochannel.model.ContentWorkgroup.contentWorkgroupRole#1]

Below is my hibernate mapping file:
ContentWorkgroup.hbm.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="corp.celcom.next.infochannel.model.ContentWorkgroup" table="CM_WORKGROUP" >
    <id name="cmWorkgroupId" type="long">
        <column name="CM_WORKGROUP_ID" precision="15" scale="0" />
```

CM_WORKGROUP
    CM_WORKGROUP_ID

ContentWorkgroupRole.hbm.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="corp.celcom.next.infochannel.model.ContentWorkgroupRole" table="CM_WORKGROUP_ROLE" >
 <id name="cmWorkgroupRoleId" type="long">
```

CM_WORKGROUP_ROLE_ID
    CM_WORKGROUP_ROLE

```
    <many-to-one name="contentWorkgroup" class="corp.celcom.next.infochannel.model.ContentWorkgroup" fetch="select">
        <column name="ROLE_ID" precision="15" scale="0" />
    </many-to-one>
```

In my ACTION class, the above mentioned error occured on this line:
**Iterator iter = cw.getContentWorkgroupRole().iterator();**

for(ContentWorkgroup cw : contentWorkgroupList)
{
        **Iterator iter = cw.getContentWorkgroupRole().iterator();**

```
    while (iter.hasNext()) {

          ContentWorkgroupRole role = (ContentWorkgroupRole) iter.next();

  if (role.getFunctionId().equalsIgnoreCase(Constant.ADD))
```

myForm.setAllowAdd(true);
      if (role.getFunctionId().equalsIgnoreCase(Constant.EDIT))
  myForm.setAllowEdit(true);
      if (role.getFunctionId().equalsIgnoreCase(Constant.DELETE))
  myForm.setAllowDelete(true);
 }
}

The weird part is when I change the ROLE_ID to Integer/Long (i.e 1-Creator, 2-Administrator), instead of using String, it work fine! I couldn't understand why and what the problem on my code.

Thanks for you help. It took me 1 day already to cope with this error. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, the display seem got abit problem. I write again here:

ContentWorkgroup.hbm.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="corp.celcom.next.infochannel.model.ContentWorkgroup" table="CM_WORKGROUP" >
    <id name="cmWorkgroupId" type="long">
        <column name="CM_WORKGROUP_ID" precision="15" scale="0" />
        <generator class="corp.celcom.next.util.MultipleTableGenerator" >
            <param name="KEYTABLE_VALUE">CM_WORKGROUP</param>
            <param name="KEYCOLUMN_VALUE">CM_WORKGROUP_ID</param>
        </generator>
    </id>
    <property name="workgroupId" type="long">
        <column name="WORKGROUP_ID" precision="15" scale="0" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <property name="srId" type="string">
        <column name="SR_ID" length="15" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <property name="contentCategoryId" type="string">
        <column name="CONTENT_CATEGORY_ID" length="40" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <property name="roleId" type="string">
        <column name="ROLE_ID" length="20" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <set name="contentWorkgroupRole" table="CM_WORKGROUP_ROLE" inverse="true">
        <key>
            <column name="ROLE_ID" length="20" not-null="true" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="corp.celcom.next.infochannel.model.ContentWorkgroupRole" />
    </set>        
</class>
```

ContentWorkgroupRole.hbm.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="corp.celcom.next.infochannel.model.ContentWorkgroupRole" table="CM_WORKGROUP_ROLE" >
    <id name="cmWorkgroupRoleId" type="long">
        <column name="CM_WORKGROUP_ROLE_ID" precision="15" scale="0" />
        <generator class="corp.celcom.next.util.MultipleTableGenerator">
            <param name="KEYCOLUMN_VALUE">CM_WORKGROUP_ROLE_ID</param>
            <param name="KEYTABLE_VALUE">CM_WORKGROUP_ROLE</param>
        </generator>
    </id>

    <many-to-one name="contentWorkgroup" class="corp.celcom.next.infochannel.model.ContentWorkgroup" fetch="select">
        <column name="ROLE_ID" precision="15" scale="0" />
    </many-to-one>

    <property name="menuId" type="string">
        <column name="MENU_ID" length="40" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <property name="functionId" type="string">
        <column name="FUNCTION_ID" length="40" not-null="true" />
    </property>
```

In my ACTION class, the above mentioned error occured on this line:
**Iterator iter = cw.getContentWorkgroupRole().iterator();**

```
for(ContentWorkgroup cw : contentWorkgroupList)
{
    Iterator iter = cw.getContentWorkgroupRole().iterator();

    while (iter.hasNext()) {

     ContentWorkgroupRole role = (ContentWorkgroupRole) iter.next();

     if (role.getFunctionId().equalsIgnoreCase(Constant.ADD))
        myForm.setAllowAdd(true);
     if (role.getFunctionId().equalsIgnoreCase(Constant.EDIT))
        myForm.setAllowEdit(true);
     if (role.getFunctionId().equalsIgnoreCase(Constant.DELETE))
        myForm.setAllowDelete(true);
 }
}
```